# Signed Java web start application with Glassfish 4.1 and Java7

Tags: java, glassfish

I am trying to run a web start application with GlassFish 4.1, JDK 1.7 update 51 locally and I encountered the "Application Blocked by Security Settings" message.

Here is what I tried to make it work:

1. Added http://hostname.localdomain.com:8080 to the Exception Site List in Java control panel. Also tried http://hostname.localdomain.com:8080/___JWSappclient/ and http://hostname.localdomain.com:8080/clientName.jnlp

2. Exported the s1as key from Glassfish's keystore.jks and imported it in to JRE cacerts:

`$ keytool -exportcert -keystore keystore.jks -alias s1as -file server.csr
$ keytool -importcert -keystore jre/lib/security/cacerts -alias s1as -file server.csr`

I could see the jars signed with the s1as key, but javaws still complains.
The JNLP is generated by Glassfish automatically using the settings from our sun-application-client.xml

Appreciate any help on how to get around this error. I realize this works fine if I use JRE7 update 21 on the client-side but I would like to try with Java 8 later on so cannot stick to Java 7. If it matters, I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your problem and have a workaround.

It seems the problem is related to the glassfish 4.1 automatically generated jnlp file and the new java security jdk 1.7 u 25 or later.

If you install java 1.7.0_21 or earlier your Java Web Start Application will start by using the javaws in the earlier distribution.

I have simplified this problem using netbeans 8.0.2, java 1.8_31 and GF 4.1. I created a Java EE "Enterprise Application Client" with no code changes. Deploy it and you cannot run it from the glassfish console nor any javaws from 7.1 u25 or later. However, if you use javaws 7.1 u21 or earlier from the command line it will start.  **Interestingly, the application is running in a java 1.8 u31 environment.**

Must be a bug in glassfish.