# Java webstart on glassfish server 4.1

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I'm building an application on Glassfish 4.1. The application is a Rest API. For the client part, I have created a java JFrame class with a number of classes underlying to use the Rest API using Jaxb. Lots to do still but that's off topic.

I'm using Netbeans for the development. For testing my JFrame class, I simply run it from out of Netbeans (Select class, menu Run > Run File). I want to take it a step further though and deliver the client application by means of java webstart. I use other apps which also do this and I think it is a neat way to deliver your java gui to a client (alternatives welcome?). Maybe I'll go to a browser based solution later but that's not a goal in the near future.

Now the webstart. I have tried 2 methods:

1. following the java tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html

Within the project of my Rest API, I created an index.html file containing the following line:

```
<script>
        deployJava.launchWebStartApplication("launch.jnlp")
</script>
```

Then the launch.jnlp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://<hostname>:8080/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>ClientTool</title>
        <vendor>Bla</vendor>
        <homepage href=""/>
        <description>Bla</description>
        <description kind="short">Bla</description>
    <icon href="bla.png" kind="default"/>
<offline-allowed/>
</information>
    <update check="background"/>
    <security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="ClientTool.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="gui.ClientFrame">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

I have deployed this, the index.html opens and starts the launch.jnlp. So far so good, but not really:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://<hostname>:8080/ClientTool.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Makes sense because I don't have a Jar file explicitly created. I obviously need to do this, but how? Must I create a seperate project in NetBeans to create the JAR? And where to put it exactly on the glassfish host?

2. by creating a new project in Netbeans, type Enterprise application client.

This works really well, You get a webstart out of the box, deploy it on glassfish and you're done. Well not really, because since Java 7 21, security has been enhanced and the way Glassfish creates the webstart config, it does not work.

See following threads for this issue. It is a reported bug but nog handled since months. And the alternative to use a lower version than Java 7 21 is simply not ok imo. Version 7 cannot even be downloaded anymore.

[Signed Java web start application with Glassfish 4.1 and Java7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307580/signed-java-web-start-application-with-glassfish-4-1-and-java7)
https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21305

Still investigating a bit further on what is going wrong exactly, the following trace was what I found:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: JAR manifest codebase mismatch for http://<hostname>:8080/___JWSappclient/___app/ClientGUI/ClientGUIClient.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.AppPolicy.grantUnrestrictedAccess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So apparently glassfish is doing something wrong with the codebase config.

Any thoughts please on how to get Glassfish and Java webstart to work?

Sapphron

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am getting the same issue, but I have gone through the various JAR that are created by Glassfish and looked at the codebase. It appears that when the Client.JAR is downloaded the codebase changes to something like the domain name (although I've not completely debugged it).